# How to efficiently unroll a matrix by value with numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a matrix `M` with values 0 through `N` within it. I'd like to unroll this matrix to create a new matrix `A` where each submatrix `A[i, :, :]` represents whether or not M == i.

The solution below uses a loop.

```
# Example Setup
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
N = 5
M = np.random.randint(0, N, size=(5,5))

# Solution with Loop
A = np.zeros((N, M.shape[0], M.shape[1]))
for i in range(N):
    A[i, :, :] = M == i
```

This yields:

```
M
array([[4, 0, 3, 3, 3],
       [1, 3, 2, 4, 0],
       [0, 4, 2, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 4],
       [3, 0, 3, 0, 2]])

M.shape
# (5, 5)


A 
array([[[0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]],
       ...
       [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]])

A.shape
# (5, 5, 5)
```

Is there a faster way, or a way to do it in a single numpy operation?

Comment: It would be better if you explain it in detail.

Comment: @MariosNikolaou just copy/paste his code and `print(M)`;`print(A)`...I edited it for you though

Comment: @Reedinationer i did it.

Comment: I would not recommend pasting output for this code as the input is randomised without a seed.

Comment: @coldspeed True, but considering the A and M are linked you can visually see what the question is about without needing to run the code. A seed would be preferable though

Comment: `i == M` compare int with array 5x5 ? and then save it in A?

Comment: @MariosNikolaou Yes integers 0 to N are being compared with each 5x5 array and being saved in A

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Broadcasted comparison is your friend:

```
B = (M[None, :] == np.arange(N)[:, None, None]).view(np.int8)

 np.array_equal(A, B)
# True
```

The idea is to expand the dimensions in such a way that the comparison can be broadcasted in the manner desired.

---

As pointed out by @Alex Riley in the comments, you can use `np.equal.outer` to avoid having to do the indexing stuff yourself,

```
B = np.equal.outer(np.arange(N), M).view(np.int8)

np.array_equal(A, B)
# True
```

Comment: Good answer - just to point out there's a superfluous newaxis in your indexing for `M` (resulting in a 4D array). You could use `M[None, :]` instead to get the 3D array. An alternative to avoid fiddly indexing is to use `np.equal.outer(np.arange(N), M).view(np.int8)`.

Comment: @AlexRiley Thanks for that! And the `outer` solution is quite neat.

Answer (score 6):

You can make use of some broadcasting here:

```
P = np.arange(N)
Y = np.broadcast_to(P[:, None], M.shape)
T = np.equal(M, Y[:, None]).astype(int)
```

---

Alternative using `indices`:

```
X, Y = np.indices(M.shape)
Z = np.equal(M, X[:, None]).astype(int)
```

Comment: This answer was really helpful towards my understanding of broadcasting, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can index into the identity matrix like so

```
 A = np.identity(N, int)[:, M]
```

or so

```
 A = np.identity(N, int)[M.T].T
```

Or use the new (v1.15.0) `put_along_axis`

```
A = np.zeros((N,5,5), int)
np.put_along_axis(A, M[None], 1, 0)
```

Note if N is much larger than 5 then creating an NxN identity matrix may be considered wasteful. We can mitigate this using stride tricks:

```
def read_only_identity(N, dtype=float):
    z = np.zeros(2*N-1, dtype)
    s, = z.strides
    z[N-1] = 1
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(z[N-1:], (N, N), (-s, s))
```

Comment: This is great, really interesting answer.

Comment: Hi Paul, this answer is really elegant, but the identity answers seem specific to the case where the N=M.shape[0]=M.shape[1]. Is the solution similarly elegant for N=/=M.shape[0]=/=M.shape[1]? Thanks for the answer, learning a lot!

Comment: @seveibar I've updated the answer. It is really just  a matter of replacing the correct 5s with Ns.