# How to create mask with one at specified index?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm learning python, numpy and machine learning. I'm trying to set up neural network from scratch and I have a problem.

I have some outputs e.g `[[2], [4], [1]]` and I'm trying to create mask for it that will look like this

```
[
[0 0 1 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 1]
[0 1 0 0 0] 
]
```

for now I'm using following code:

```
tmpY = np.array(Y)
tmp = np.zeros([m, 10])
for i in range (0, m):
    index = tmpY[i][0]
    tmp[i][index] = 1
```

But I think there is a cleaner way.

**Edit:**

Thanks guys for your help. I think I've found solution that will work best for me

```
C = np.array([[0], [2], [4], [2], [4], [1] ,[3], [8], [5], [3], [1], [2]])
np.eye(C.shape[0], np.amax(C) + 1, dtype=int)[C.flatten()]

[[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

I'll leave it here in case someone else will look it.

Comment: Very similar: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55543949/7207392

Answer (score 0):

your solution is correct, this is just a little cleaner version

```
indices = [[2],[4],[1]]
mask = np.zeros((m,10),dtype=np.uint8)

for i,indices in enumerate(indices): mask[i,indices] = 1
```

not sure where you get that `indices` array from but you have some sort of condition by which you want to mask the original you can do:

```
original = np.random.uniform((100,100))

mask = np.zeros(original.shape,dtype=np.uint8)
mask[condition(original)] = 1 # eg mask[original < 0.5] = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

sklearn has a class that can help you do this. You can use `OneHotEncoder` to create the mask as per the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html)

In your example

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
enc = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
X = [[2], [4], [1]]
enc.fit(X)
```

Then the output looks like:

```
enc.transform(X).toarray()
array([[0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 0.]])
```

**EDIT:**
You'll notice the output here has 3 elements for each transformed entry; this is because category 3 does not appear in the data we use to fit `OneHotEncoder`

Comment: this only works if there is at least 1 `1` mask at the maximum length index required for the output, at the very least this needs to be padded.

Comment: ok, what if it's string? what if you don't know the desired length? the for loop method dies not generalize well with any other data type

Comment: a mask is always integer type

Comment: the mask is, what you are trying to encode is not necessarily always an int